# How to use the Range Object in JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, range

This is a really wide question. And hopefully i can simplify it. I have the following HTML in my body

```
<span>my <strong>text</strong> section seems to <a href="#">be</a> here</span>
```

I want to get the text of this span. I know i can do this with the Range Object and then the .tostring(). But how can i get all the parts in the correct order?

- my
- text
- section seems to
- be
- here

Answer (score 1):

If all you are trying to do is get the text in that span, you could do:

```
document.getElementsByTagName( 'span' )[ 0 ].innerText
```

If you specifically want an array of the results, broken into parts, I wrote a quick function to accomplish this:

```
function getText( node ) {
    var children = node.childNodes,
        len = children.length,
        arr = [],
        child, i;
    for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        child = children[ i ];
        if ( child.nodeType === 3 ) arr.push( child.data );
        else arr.push.apply( arr, getText( child ) );
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Here is a JSFiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/nxgcd/1/

Comment: `child.nodeType == 3` is a better test than `child instanceof Text`: it works in more browsers (all major browsers since the 1990s, in fact).

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to get the text without the HTML without using RegEx then just use:

```
document.getElementById("theSpan").innerText
//or
$("#theSpan").text() //Jquery
```

Here is a [Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/429q7/1/) and [Jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/FY66u/1/) JSFiddle